# Bootstrap modal cuts from left when window resize

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal whose width is 900px. Initially when i tried resizing window it cut of top and left part. but after changing css i was able to stop the top part from being cut off. the problem is that it is cutting off the left part still. Figure shows the problem.

[image]

The right part is working fine ie. when scrolled it shows properly.

CSS

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}  

.modal.fade.in {
  top: 10%;   
}   

#myModal{width:900px}
```

JS

```
$('#myModal').css({
    'margin-left': function () {
        return -($(this).width() / 2);
    }
});
```

I dont want to make it responsive . How can i do this? tnx in advance

Demo http://jsbin.com/IBaZILa/2

Comment: a fixed width to class `modal-content` would to the trick

Comment: @Nesmar tried everything it is not listening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your provided URL, I think you have modified bootstrap.css file. The .modal class have "margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;" property and your code contains "margin-left: -280px".

So set it as original ie. "margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;" also set "top:50%"

Then remove 'inline margin-left css' generating by JS code

```
$('#myModal').css({
'margin-left': function () {
    return -($(this).width() / 2);
}
});
```

Then remove custom class written on page

```
.modal{
    position: absolute,
    margin: 0
}
```

Then apply width for #modal to 50% (To make it responsive, You need to give width in %). Currently you are setting with 900px, It not fits on screen as for '.modal' class 'left:50%' attribute is defined.

left:50% is working for default width 560px, Which is defined in bootstrap.css file.

To increase #modal width you need to set 'left' attribute of .modal class.